# What is the missing number in this grid composed by 25 values?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

Well, I have created a simple table with 25 values, inside it, all the data is readable, except for one that is hidden.

Can you guess it?

The table:

[image: The table]

Comment: Yeah, it's great you caught this detail

Comment: Is the two different background colors relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> 90

Reason

> The slightly shaded squares are the sum of the adjacent(up, down, left, right) white squares. So, the "? is equal to 5+39+16+30 which is 90.

Comment: You got it, nice one :)